# Pass values from default page to asp.net handler

Tags: asp.net, session, query-string, handler

I have a simple html hidden field as shown below

```
<input id="currentDirectory" type="hidden" runat="server" value="123"/>
```

Now I need to pass this hidden field value using query string to asp.net handler ans I have done as shown below but it dosen't pass the value.

In Default.aspx page:

```
var value = $("#currentDirectory").val();
url: 'Uploader.ashx?myvalue=' + value,
```

Accessing in Handler.ashx:

```
Dim myvar As String= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("myvalue")
```

Can anyone say me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Don't read it from `Session`. Read it from `Request`

Comment: @Yuiry Galanter- That did the magic..Thnks for your time:)